# Implement Windows 8 Tile "Click" animation with css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, microsoft-metro

If you see the video over here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212680.aspx, you will notice that the 2nd tile scales down immediately, stays scaled-down for few milliseconds then comes up to normal state.

I tried to mimic this behaviour by reducing the width and height by 2px on `:active` and gave `background-size: cover`. But I am not able to create the delay in scaling back to normal with this approach.

This should be possible with CSS3 animations but I am not able to map out an approach.
Can anyone give me a direction to go from here?

**EDIT:** Here's a jsfiddle of what I have tried:  http://jsfiddle.net/p3Wbh/

** EDIT: **: Updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Wbh/1/ with jQuery implementation for the "held down" effect. Looking for a way to do this in css3.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updayed the post with the js fiddle link

Comment: Please add some more description .... Like what are the contents .. its not always required to animate a div .... if Listviews are available .. so Please put down some more description ..

Comment: Is the behaviour in the video not just because the button was held down?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the video shows the interaction for "touch and click" feedback. Regardless of button getting held down or not, I need an animation on click. This should be possible with css3 animations (there is a delay property) but I am not able to make it work

Comment: I m Not sure about css3 but I can go ahead with a javascript code if you wish to :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for javascript / winJS I can explain it ... but the css3 property I don't know about that ..

Pleas ego through the Gestures link
[Gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here use 
1 -> MSPointerDown
2 -> MSPointerUp
3 -> MSPointerOver
4 -> MSPointerOut

Animate your tile by setting css properties in these events .. :) I hope this works for you .....

Like in pointer down add the css you wrote for that pressed look and in pointer up or move add the animation + css for unpressed look ...

Hope the suggestion helps :)